# How to search for persons with high ranking

Tags: support, statistics, users

Suppose I want to find individuals who rank high in answering questions with certain tags. How would I frame the search query and where do I enter it?

Comment: Go to [tags](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags), then click on for eg: [tikz-pgf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), next see [top users](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tikz-pgf/topusers), it's categorised into 1) Top `tikz-pgf` Answerers 2)Top `tikz-pgf` Askers all time and past 30 days data. Also look at http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/queries. I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Data Explorer is your friend but you need to be familiar with SQL  language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no specific search query for this in the StackExchange user interface. However, to find what you're looking for, you can visit:

```
https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/<tag>/topusers
```

where you specify `<tag>`. Alternatively, follow

1. [Tags](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags)
2. Hover of the tag of interest and select "Top users":

   [image]
3. Resulting screen highlights a number of statistics associated with the tag, including the top askers and answerers:

   [image]

   Technically you don't have to do this from the tags window. You could hover over any tag you're interested in, and it will display the fly-out.